# Getting String value from a table in Sqlite

Tags: c, sqlite

I have a table with 3 columns. I need to select a record by unique id and print the other 2 records

Im using

```
 rs = get_result("SELECT sid FROM sdata WHERE sid='%s';",sid);
```

Im able to get the resultset-I verified that.

But this line produces an error

```
 printf(1,0,(unsigned char *)resultset.recordset[0][1],0);
```

Isn't this the proper way to print records.

UPDATE:

Im developing this for a embedded device and cross compiling against `gcc-4.1.2-glibc-2.5-nptl-3/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc`

```
resultset get_result(const char* fmt, ...)
{
    int success = 0;
    int nrow=0, ncol=0, i=0, j=0, count=0;
    char *err_messg;
    char **result;
    char ***recordset;
    resultset resultset_table;

    char sql_string[1500];//this honestly needs to be more elegant; will do for now
    va_list args;   
    va_start(args, fmt);
    sql_string[0] = '\0';
    ret = vsprintf(sql_string, fmt, args);
    va_end(args);   
    fprintf(stdout,"\n%s\n", sql_string);

    SQLITE = 1;

    //initialize resultset_table;
    resultset_table.rows = 0;
    resultset_table.cols = 0;
    resultset_table.recordset = NULL;

    ret = sqlite3_get_table(
                    db_conn,              
                    sql_string,
                    &result,
                    &nrow,
                    &ncol,
                    &err_messg
                );

    fprintf(stdout,"nrow=%d ncol=%d\n",nrow,ncol);

    recordset = (char ***)malloc(nrow * sizeof(char **));
    for(count=ncol; count<((nrow + 1)*ncol); count++)
    {
        recordset[i] = (char **)malloc(ncol * sizeof(char *));
        for(j=0; j<ncol; j++)
        {
            err_printf("%s ",result[count]);//
            recordset[i][j] = (char *) malloc( (strlen(result[count]) + 1) );
            strcpy(recordset[i][j], result[count]);

            if(j != (ncol - 1))
                count++;
        }
        i++;
        err_printf("\n");//
    }
    sqlite3_free_table(result);

    if( ret != SQLITE_OK )
    {
        fprintf(stdout,"SQL error: %s\n", err_messg);
        success = 0; 
        }

    else
    {
        resultset_table.rows = nrow;
        resultset_table.cols = ncol;
        resultset_table.recordset = recordset;
        success = 1;
    }

    SQLITE = 0;
    return resultset_table;
}
```

***Error:***
 error: expected expression before 'resultset'

Comment: More info is needed here. The SQLite3 API does not contain a get_result function as far as I can see. Also you don't state the error, or even which compiler you use.

Comment: Which access lib are you using? This aren't sqlite3 functions you're calling.

Comment: @Felix Bytow Im using gcc and cross compiling against arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc

Comment: Post `get_result` function code.

Comment: @LPs Please see update.

Comment: @Murphy Please see update.

Comment: Your sample is still incomplete. Where is `resultset` declared? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Murphy `get_result` method returns a resultset

Comment: Shouldn't be `rs` instead of `resultset`?

Comment: @LPs That fixed the error.LOL :) Stupid me.

Comment: Your code is very complicated. Take a look at `sqlite3_prepare_v2` lib function. It will shrink your code.

Comment: @LPs I have been using object  oriented languages for a while now .. so they report undeclared variables... but c does not

Comment: @LPs Actually i have not written this function... im reusing it... i dont know why such big code to pull a resultset.

Comment: @LPs Hope this is the correct way to read column data.

Comment: My personal opinion is: actually not . Take a look [HERE](http://zetcode.com/db/sqlitec/)

Comment: @LPs Can you please tell me what the integers (1,1) in rs.recordset[1][1] represent

Comment: Sorry, I'm not getting you...

Comment: @LPs I mean i have this table with 3 columns.When i print using rs.recordset[0][0].. i get the first column value but inorder to print the second column when i use rs.recordset[0][1].. the device prints some gibberish(im using kermit )

Comment: I really don't know. You have to debug your code. BTW for SO your posted `printf` is weird.

Comment: @LPs Again stupid me.. i wrote >select sid from.. . Need more concentration :)

Comment: @LPs I just replaced a function with printf.. so its understandable.I mean the Device has an SDK..im calling it from C.